# Creating numpy array with empty columns using genfromtxt

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation, genfromtxt

I am importing data using `numpy.genfromtxt`, and I would like to add a field of values derived from some of those within the dataset. As this is a structured array, it seems like the most simple, efficient way of adding a new column to the array is by using `numpy.lib.recfunctions.append_fields()`. I found a good description of this library [HERE](http://www.astropython.org/resource/2011/7/recfunctions).

Is there a way of doing this without copying the array, perhaps by forcing `genfromtxt` to create an empty column to which I can append derived values?

Comment: the first parameter to `genfromtxt` can be a generator, within which, you can create an empty column on each line of your file while you're reading it in.

Comment: mtadd, i've just ran into this problem again, and I'm wondering if you could illustrate what you are referring to in an answer. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example using a generator to add a field to a data file using **genfromtxt**

Our example data file will be *data.txt* with the contents:

```
1,11,1.1
2,22,2.2
3,33,3.3
```

So

```
In [19]: np.genfromtxt('data.txt',delimiter=',')
Out[19]:
array([[  1. ,  11. ,   1.1],
       [  2. ,  22. ,   2.2],
       [  3. ,  33. ,   3.3]])
```

If we make a generator such as:

```
def genfield():
    for line in open('data.txt'):
        yield '0,' + line
```

which prepends a comma-delimited 0 to each line of the file, then:

```
In [22]: np.genfromtxt(genfield(),delimiter=',')
Out[22]:
array([[  0. ,   1. ,  11. ,   1.1],
       [  0. ,   2. ,  22. ,   2.2],
       [  0. ,   3. ,  33. ,   3.3]])
```

You can do the same thing with comprehensions as follows:

```
In [26]: np.genfromtxt(('0,'+line for line in open('data.txt')),delimiter=',')
Out[26]:
array([[  0. ,   1. ,  11. ,   1.1],
       [  0. ,   2. ,  22. ,   2.2],
       [  0. ,   3. ,  33. ,   3.3]])
```

Comment: Brilliant. If only `genfromtxt` could take a regex for the delimiter, it would now be a perfect tool for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to make `genfromtxt` read this:

```
11,12,13,14,15
21,22,
31,32,33,34,35
41,42,43,,45
```

using:

```
import numpy as np
print np.genfromtxt('tmp.txt',delimiter=',',filling_values='0')
```

but it did not work. I had to change the input adding commas to represent the empty columns:

```
11,12,13,14,15
21,22,,,
31,32,33,34,35
41,42,43,,45
```

then it worked, returning:

```
[[ 11.  12.  13.  14.  15.]
 [ 21.  22.   0.   0.   0.]
 [ 31.  32.  33.  34.  35.]
 [ 41.  42.  43.   0.  45.]]
```

Comment: Thanks Saullo. What I am actually looking for is to have an additional row, that does not exist in the data file that I am reading in.

Comment: @shootingstars to add additional rows you can use `np.vstack((a, np.zeros((num_rows, a.shape[1]))))`

Comment: My problem is that i call this with one of the fields being a `datetime` object, which prevents the stack and numpy.lib.recfuntions `add_field` from merging the arrays.